# ADO.NET creating new Entities object/context exception

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a problem with following code:

```
public static IQueryable<Osoba> GetOsoby()
{
    using (WeryfikacjaEntities context = new WeryfikacjaEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<Osoba> user = from s in context.Osobas select s;
        return user;
    }
}
```

Actually problem occurs in third line, to be specific at:

```
WeryfikacjaEntities context = new WeryfikacjaEntities()
```

I'm getting an exception whose inner exception says something like (can't paste it, unless u know Polish): "Cannot find given connection named in configuration, this connection is not supposed for use with EntityClient provider or is incorrect".

Exception itselfs gives me something about XamlParse

I've use `EntityFramework` wizard, so I guess connection is ok.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Oh `GetOsoby()` method is called this way:

```
public static List<Worker> GetWorkers()
{
    var u = Class1.GetOsoby().Select(x => new Worker
    {
        _id = x.ID,
        _name = x.Imie,
        _surname = x.Nazwisko,
        _birthDate = x.DataUrodzenia,
        _position = x.Stanowisko,
        _earnings = x.Wynagrodzenie,
        _ageGroup = x.GrupaWiekowa,
        _department = Class1.GetDzialy().Where(
            y => y.ID == Class1.GetStanowiska().Where(
                z => z.ID == x.Stanowisko).FirstOrDefault().ID)
            .FirstOrDefault().ID
    }).ToList();

    return (List<Worker>)u;
}
```

This is the Stacktrace for the inner exception:

```
   in System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   in System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
   in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
   in ClassLibrary1.WeryfikacjaEntities..ctor() w C:\Users\Rufix\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Zadanie 5\ClassLibrary1\Model1.Designer.cs:wiersz 40
   in ClassLibrary1.Class1.GetOsoby() w C:\Users\Rufix\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Zadanie 5\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs:wiersz 13
   in Zadanie_5.Worker.GetWorkers() w C:\Users\Rufix\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Zadanie 5\Zadanie 5\Worker.cs:wiersz 39
   in Zadanie_5.MainWindow..ctor() w C:\Users\Rufix\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Zadanie 5\Zadanie 5\MainWindow.xaml.cs:wiersz 26

TargetSite: {Void ChangeConnectionString(System.String)}
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring context you can specify a connection string and you can declare your db context like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext() : base("SomeConnectionString"){}
    {
```

have you made sure that you're calling the right connection string?

If not, please paste the rest of the inner exception so we can see it

Comment: There's only one connection and I'm sure I connected to proper base. Anyway what would you like to see from that inner exception? I've added some info up there.